# Supply parameters to a SQL Server function in a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view, sql-function

I have a view

```
Create View v1 
as
    select a.Explanation1, a.Explanation2
    from fx_getData(null, null) data
    inner join Explanations1 a on data.Explanation1ID = a.ID
    inner join Explanations2 b on data.Explanation2ID = b.ID
```

The function is

```
create function fx_getData
    (@year varchar(4) = NULL,
     @month varchar(2) = NULL)
return
(
    select *   
    from data 
    where year = @year and month = @month
)
```

I want to pass parameters to this function from the view as otherwise it will run for a really long time.

How can I do that ?

EDIT: the parameters for the view need to come from the UI for this app. 
It will have to be some kind of a parameterized view as otherwise the query will become something like:-

```
select * from v1 where year = 'y1'
```

This will get everything from the function and select from those values.
Hence it will run for a really long time.

How can I filter first and then join ?

Comment: You replace the `null`s with the values you want.  Somehow, I'm missing what your question is.

Comment: So then you should pass those values from the view. What is preventing you?

Comment: You can't pass parameter values through a view into a function.  You have to specify them within the query in the view.  In order to do this you would need to convert the view to a function or stored procedure, or you would need to change the view to do a CROSS/OUTER APPLY or something like that.